# Error con importacion de Nugets para nueva aplicacion xamarin en vs 2017

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, nuget

al momento de intentar importar algunos nuggets como el que esta en pantalla, me sale el mensaje que esta en pantalla, he intentado crear un proyecto en el framework 4.6.1 y el error persiste

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @sgrysoft podrias proveer un repositorio en github con el codigo minimo para reproducir tu problema? Adicionalmente te diria que crear una liberia con target framework 4.6.1 no es el camino correcto...